# Show Taxonomy Before Woocommerce Product Title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have renamed the taxonomy 'product_tag' to 'artist' using the following snippet and i would like it to show in single product page and in archive page.

```
function change_cat_object() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['product_tag']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Artist';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Artist';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Artist';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Artist';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Artist';
    $labels->new_item = 'Artist';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Artist';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Artists';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Artists found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Artists found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Artists';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Artist';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Artist';
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_cat_object' );
```

In single product page i used this code and works fine:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_add_product_cat', 0 );
function custom_add_product_cat(){
    global $product;
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_tag');
    $count = count($product_cats);
    $categories = '';
    foreach($product_cats as $key => $cat){
        $categories .= $cat->name;
        if($key < ($count-1)){
            $categories .= ', ';
        }
    }

    echo '<div class="artist-name">'. $categories . '</div>';
}
```

In archive page, product title and price are an overlay to the products image. I am using 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' and the taxonomy doesn't show; if use 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' instead, the taxonomy is displayed but in between the product title and the product price.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_add_product_tag', 0 );
function custom_add_product_tag(){
    global $product;
    $product_tags = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_tag');
    $count = count($product_tags);
    $categories = '';
    foreach($product_tags as $key => $tag){
        $categories .= $tag->name;
        if($key < ($count-1)){
            $categories .= ', ';
        }
    }

    echo '<div class="artist-tag">'. $categories . '</div>';
}
```

Below the product image in archive pages, where 'RING RING' is the product title and 'ABBA' is the taxonomy:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is because your theme (or a plugin) is already making customizations and changes to the default WooCommerce behavior, and nobody can guess those changes by magic.

Comment: $product->id should be $product->get_id() also try using wc_get_product_tag_list() instead ?

Comment: @Snuffy Thanks for the suggestion, i tried it nut didn't work.